# C++ not finding class method definition

Tags: c++

I'm likely just doing something dumb, but I can't figure it out. I have a class called VariableList thats defined in a .h and a .cc file as follows: (some of the .cc file ommitted)

Header:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _VARIABLELIST_H_    
#define _VARIABLELIST_H_    
#include "Variable.h"
#include <algorithm>    
#include <vector>    
using namespace std;

class VariableList    
{
public:
    VariableList(void);
    VariableList(const VariableList &other, bool setLiveness = false, bool liveVal = false);
    void Add(const simple_instr* instr);
    void Add(Variable var);
    void SortAndRemoveDuplicates();
    bool CompareLiveness(const VariableList &var);

    int size();
    vector<Variable>::iterator begin();
    vector<Variable>::iterator end();

    //Operator Overloads
    Variable& operator[] (int i);   

protected:  
    int currentID;
    vector<Variable> variableList;
        void Add(const simple_reg* ref, bool checkForDuplicated = true);
private:
};
#endif
```

.cc file

```
#include "VariableList.h"
VariableList::VariableList(void)
{
    currentID = 0;
}

VariableList::VariableList(const VariableList &other, bool setLiveness = false, bool liveVal = false) //: currentID(0), variableList(other.variableList)
{
    currentID = 0;
    variableList(other.variableList);
    if (setLiveness) 
    {
       for( int i = 0; i < size(); i++ )
            variableList[i].isLive = LiveVal;
    }
}

//Rest Omitted as it doesnt matter for the problem I'm having
```

I'm attempting to use it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" { 
#include <simple.h>
}
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include "Instruction.h"
#include "Variable.h"
#include "VariableList.h"
using namespace std;
class VariableList;
simple_instr* do_procedure (simple_instr *inlist, char *proc_name)
{
    Instruction inst(*inlist);
    Variable var;
    cout << var.GetID();
    VariableList varList;
    return inlist;
}
```

but whenever I try to compile, the compiler says "undefined reference to VariableList::VariableList()" as though it's not seeing my .cc file. Is there more I need to do for it to see my definititions in the .cc file?

Comment: Do you use a Makefile? You have to link your object-files (`VariableList.o` and `procedure.o`) together …

Comment: Compilers never see .cc files other than what you give them on the command line. Probably you need to link together several `.o` files, the exact details depend what compiler you're using.

Comment: I dont think you need 'class VariableList;' in your last code sample. It should be forward declared already by the inclusion of the header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you adding all your .cc files when compiling?

`g++ -o myExecuatable file1.cc file2.cc file3.cc ...`